# Swiftmailer throwing error on SetBody

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am having this error using SwiftMailer Libs.

```
$message_body = "Body of message";

$transport = send_mail_transport();

//Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

//Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();


  $message->setBody('$message_body'); //displays $message_body in mail client
  $message->setBody($message_body); //throws parse error in browser
  $message->setBody('Body of message'); //Works well. displays Body of message in mail client
```

//What could be the problem as i intent to get values from variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Figured it out
Changed it to

```
$message->setBody("$message_body");
```

Interestingly this was not documented in their manual.

Comment: You must have made some error. `"$message_body"` is exactly the same like `$message_body` if `$message_body` is a string variable. As you have not given any concrete information about the parse error, it's not easy to say what went wrong. I'm just saying this, not that you think the SwiftMailer Manual would be missing anything at that point.